# Accessing common jar file from App as well as from Android Library Project

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries, android-library

I have a static java library(classes.jar) file which has source code common to a Android Library Project and the dependent app which is calling this Android Library project.

I'm using ant env to compile the code on linux machine.

But when I include this jar file under libs folders of both ALP and App, it gives the following compilation error :

```
[dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/android/test/ProgramCache;
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
       [dx] 1 error; aborting
```

How would I solve this problem of common jar?

Comment: "when I include this jar file under libs folders of both ALP and App". What happens if you don't include it in the App? Maybe it already gets resolves/included because App depends on ALP?

Comment: If I dont include the jar in app, it will give compilation error for all those jar APIs being used by app.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I won't mix up rules about building android projects in eclipse with building projects in ant with the android toolchain...  (And with any luck, you won't have to do both like I do :))

Any jar files in the /libs folders of android shared libraries are automatically included by the command line android build tools.  While I can't remember if they are copied on disk, or only added to the build path during compilation, it should suffice to simply remove the jar from App/libs.

Another word of advice when dealing with this problem, ant clean early and often.  Its very easy to accidentally build some classes into one of your project jars and then have conflicts later.

Comment: I want to make my app as plug-able. Hence dont want to go with the shared library concept, where the lib would be stored in sdk. Can you be able to specify a design where my entire code, including that of jar would be sitting under my apk?